# HTML pop up PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I'm currently making a basic website for fun at my work. This website will just help us save on paper so we dont have to print out everything, we can just have a website with all the .PDF files we need.

Right now I'm at the very beginning. I'm using Microsoft Web Expression 4. I've created a DWT so all pages that I create will mimic each other. I have created a `mystyles.css` for all the good-looking parts of the website. And I have created a `myscripts.js` for any JavaScripting that I need (although I don't know what to put in there just yet).

My issue comes in when trying to add in a pop up window. For example, when I click on a little banner that says "Channel Line Up" I want an in-page pop up to appear with the PDF file, where I can <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for certain channels, I can click outside of the popup and it will X out, and have a little X at the top right to close out as well. I have tried modals, but I can't get it to work right. The best code I have been able to find is this:

```
<div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
    <img src="images\channel.png" alt="Channel Line Up" style="width:850px;"></a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
        <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="images\chlineup.jpg" style="width:1000px;height:2100px;" alt="DirecTV Channel Line Up">
    </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

in my header.

This works (for JPG as you can see in my code) But when I add multiple instances of this, leaving one instance in my header, it will only pull the same picture every time.

So I rename and re-source everything, but no matter which button I click on, it only will bring up the first picture that I sourced. Below is my code:

```
<div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
    <img src="images\channel.png" alt="Channel Line Up" style="width:850px;"></a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="images\chlineup.jpg" style="width:1000px;height:2100px;" alt="DirecTV Channel Line Up">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
    <img src="images\buttoncheat.png" alt="Account Creations Cheat Sheet" style="width:850px;"></a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="C:\Users\bbusa\Desktop\callcenter website\images\cheatsheet.jpg" style="width:800px;height:1111px;" alt="Account Creations Cheat Sheet">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
    <img src="images\buttonprice.png" alt="Account Creations Price Guide" style="width:850px;"></a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="C:\Users\bbusa\Desktop\callcenter website\images\pricing.jpg" style="width:1000px;height:2100px;" alt="DirecTV Pricing Guide">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
    <img src="images\buttonverif.png" alt="Account Creations Verification Script" style="width:850px;"></a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="C:\Users\bbusa\Desktop\callcenter website\images\verif.jpg" style="width:1000px;height:2100px;" alt="Account Creations Verification Script">
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I scrap this and try to make a image MODAL work? I've tried using modals, but I couldn't even get them to work properly. This one works but only for the first button. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your unique pop-up divs have the same ID. Try changing this and seeing if it helps. Classes can be re-used but IDs should only appear once per page. Your anchor link should point to the specific div you want to open up.

If you're interested in using a third-party solution, research Lightbox.

Comment: so do something like:
  <div id="pageFour" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
     <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
     <img src="images\buttonverif.png" alt="Account Creations Verification Script" style="width:850px;"></a>
      <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupFour">
       <a href="#pageFour" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="source" style="width:1000px;height:2100px;" alt="anything">
      </div>
    </div>